# Display any received comments whilst answering a question

Tags: feature-request

When answering a question you will get a notification when someone has also posted an answer just before you have.  This is very useful - there is no point in submitting an answer when your answer is identical!

Is there anyway to have a similar notification if someone has also posted a comment before you have submitted an answer?

Sometimes I have been working on an answer and after submitting the answer, maybe one or more comments have been added to the question which would have been useful to know before submitting.